# Connecting to 5 Ghz WiFi, whereas on 2.4 Ghz works just fine

Tags: networking, wireless

I have an quirky issue connecting my Linux machine to WiFi router only on 5Ghz band, whereas on 2.4Ghz everything works fine(, but limiting the internet bandwidth severly).
I suppose that's not router fault, because I'm able to connect my Galaxy Note 10 using 5Ghz band with full speed. I suspect that is simply a Linux configuration problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 with 5.8.0-41-generic kernel and Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter.

But let's start at the very beginning. I could suspect that the problem may have someting with switching to Ubuntu 20.10, but I'm not in 100% certain. I've discovered that **iw reg** setting was erased after some system updates:

```
# iw reg get
global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

# iw reg set PL
# iw reg get
global
country PL: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

The current settings of my WiFi router are:

```
2.4Ghz
802.11 Mode: Mixed (802.11b, 802.11g and 802.11n)
Channel: Auto (Current Ch. 1)
Bandwidth: Auto
Power: 100

5Ghz
802.11 Mode: Mixed (802.11a and 802.11n/ac)
Channel: Auto (Current Ch. 100/80)
Bandwidth: Auto
Power: 100
```

I think that listing below could be helpful:

```
# iw list
Wiphy phy0
    wiphy index: 0
    max # scan SSIDs: 1
    max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
    Band 1:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5160 MHz [32] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5170 MHz [34] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5180 MHz [36] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5190 MHz [38] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5210 MHz [42] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5230 MHz [46] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (23.0 dBm)
            * 5250 MHz [50] (disabled)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5270 MHz [54] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5290 MHz [58] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5310 MHz [62] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5330 MHz [66] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5340 MHz [68] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5350 MHz [70] (disabled)
            * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
            * 5370 MHz [74] (disabled)
            * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
            * 5390 MHz [78] (disabled)
            * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
            * 5410 MHz [82] (disabled)
            * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
            * 5430 MHz [86] (disabled)
            * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
            * 5450 MHz [90] (disabled)
            * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
            * 5470 MHz [94] (disabled)
            * 5480 MHz [96] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5490 MHz [98] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5510 MHz [102] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5530 MHz [106] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5550 MHz [110] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5570 MHz [114] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5590 MHz [118] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5610 MHz [122] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5630 MHz [126] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5650 MHz [130] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5670 MHz [134] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5690 MHz [138] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5710 MHz [142] (26.0 dBm) (radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (disabled)
            * 5725 MHz [145] (disabled)
            * 5730 MHz [146] (disabled)
            * 5735 MHz [147] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5740 MHz [148] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5750 MHz [150] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5755 MHz [151] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5760 MHz [152] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5770 MHz [154] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5775 MHz [155] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5780 MHz [156] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5790 MHz [158] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5795 MHz [159] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5800 MHz [160] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5810 MHz [162] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5815 MHz [163] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5820 MHz [164] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5830 MHz [166] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5840 MHz [168] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5850 MHz [170] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5860 MHz [172] (13.0 dBm)
            * 5870 MHz [174] (disabled)
            * 5880 MHz [176] (disabled)
            * 5890 MHz [178] (disabled)
            * 5900 MHz [180] (disabled)
            * 5910 MHz [182] (disabled)
            * 5920 MHz [184] (disabled)
            * 5930 MHz [186] (disabled)
            * 5940 MHz [188] (disabled)
            * 5950 MHz [0] (disabled)
            * 5960 MHz [2] (disabled)
            * 5970 MHz [4] (disabled)
            * 5980 MHz [6] (disabled)
            * 5990 MHz [8] (disabled)
            * 6000 MHz [10] (disabled)
            * 6010 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 6020 MHz [14] (disabled)
            * 6030 MHz [16] (disabled)
            * 6040 MHz [18] (disabled)
            * 6050 MHz [20] (disabled)
            * 6060 MHz [22] (disabled)
            * 6070 MHz [24] (disabled)
            * 6080 MHz [26] (disabled)
            * 6090 MHz [28] (disabled)
            * 6100 MHz [30] (disabled)
            * 6110 MHz [32] (disabled)
            * 6120 MHz [34] (disabled)
            * 6130 MHz [36] (disabled)
            * 6140 MHz [38] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * join_ibss
         * set_pmksa
         * del_pmksa
         * flush_pmksa
         * connect
         * disconnect
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    interface combinations are not supported
    Device supports scan flush.
    Supported extended features:
```

```
# iwlist wlp8s0 frequency 
wlp8s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
```

I would appreciate any clues what is happening and how to utilize 5Ghz band.

---

**UPDATE #1** The content of `journal -f -u NetworkManager`. Please note that **UPC241233881 is 2.4G** and **UPC501233881 is 5G**, so 00:57:23 is successful connection to 2.4G and in 00:59:12 I tried to connect to 5G.

```
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3259] device (wlp8s0): disconnecting for new activation request.
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3259] device (wlp8s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3264] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3288] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="8a3a5695-d9bd-44ed-be63-3c92a72f2d72" name="UPC501233881" pid=1916 uid=1000 result="success"
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3527] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3541] device (wlp8s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3910] dhcp4 (wlp8s0): canceled DHCP transaction
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3911] dhcp4 (wlp8s0): state changed bound -> done
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3958] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3963] device (wlp8s0): Activation: starting connection 'UPC501233881' (8a3a5695-d9bd-44ed-be63-3c92a72f2d72)
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3983] device (wlp8s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3988] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.3995] device (wlp8s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4000] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'UPC501233881' has security, but secrets are required.
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4001] device (wlp8s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4035] device (wlp8s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4039] device (wlp8s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4041] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'UPC501233881' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4042] Config: added 'ssid' value 'UPC501233881'
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4042] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4042] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4042] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4042] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
lut 09 00:59:12 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828752.4042] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
lut 09 00:59:16 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828756.4331] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
lut 09 00:59:21 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828761.2314] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
lut 09 00:59:21 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828761.3331] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
lut 09 00:59:21 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828761.3404] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
lut 09 00:59:21 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828761.3525] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> group_handshake
lut 09 00:59:21 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828761.3558] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: group_handshake -> disconnected
lut 09 00:59:21 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828761.4578] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
lut 09 00:59:26 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828766.0846] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
lut 09 00:59:26 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828766.1370] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
lut 09 00:59:26 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828766.6375] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
lut 09 00:59:31 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828771.3011] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
lut 09 00:59:31 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828771.3611] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
lut 09 00:59:32 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828772.3619] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
lut 09 00:59:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828777.1410] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
lut 09 00:59:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828777.1971] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
lut 09 00:59:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <warn>  [1612828777.5758] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
lut 09 00:59:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828777.5758] device (wlp8s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:37 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <warn>  [1612828777.5775] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9885] device (wlp8s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9893] device (wlp8s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9898] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'UPC501233881' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9898] Config: added 'ssid' value 'UPC501233881'
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9899] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9899] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9899] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9899] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
lut 09 00:59:41 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828781.9899] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
lut 09 00:59:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828782.0264] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
lut 09 00:59:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828782.1339] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
lut 09 00:59:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828782.1454] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
lut 09 00:59:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828782.1581] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> group_handshake
lut 09 00:59:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828782.1597] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: group_handshake -> disconnected
lut 09 00:59:42 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828782.2633] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
lut 09 00:59:56 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828796.8002] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
lut 09 00:59:56 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828796.8569] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
lut 09 01:00:06 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828806.8801] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
lut 09 01:00:07 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <warn>  [1612828807.5752] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
lut 09 01:00:07 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828807.5752] device (wlp8s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 01:00:07 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <warn>  [1612828807.5774] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8551] device (wlp8s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8555] device (wlp8s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8558] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'UPC501233881' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8559] Config: added 'ssid' value 'UPC501233881'
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8559] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8559] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8559] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8559] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
lut 09 01:00:09 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828809.8559] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
lut 09 01:00:11 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828811.6197] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
lut 09 01:00:11 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828811.7263] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
lut 09 01:00:11 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828811.7346] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
lut 09 01:00:11 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828811.7424] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> group_handshake
lut 09 01:00:11 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828811.7477] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: group_handshake -> disconnected
lut 09 01:00:11 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828811.8476] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
lut 09 01:00:27 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828827.4209] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
lut 09 01:00:27 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828827.4810] device (wlp8s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
lut 09 01:00:35 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <warn>  [1612828835.5791] device (wlp8s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
lut 09 01:00:35 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828835.5791] device (wlp8s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lut 09 01:00:35 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828835.5799] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
lut 09 01:00:35 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <warn>  [1612828835.5816] device (wlp8s0): Activation: failed for connection 'UPC501233881'
lut 09 01:00:35 PRZEDNICZEK01 NetworkManager[837]: <info>  [1612828835.5823] device (wlp8s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

---

**UPDATE 2**
In the Network manager, there's **WPA & WPA2 Personal** option selected and router has **WPA-Personal** with authentication = **WPA2** and encryption = **AES** as depicted below:
[image: WPA2 on both ends]

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I updated the question with output of `iwlist wlp8s0 frequency`. Of course I tried to assign channels manually, but without success. However, I've noticed two things: 1. after reboot `iw reg get` drops previously assigned country and retreats to **00**; 2. On my WiFi router the **unchangable** country is set Irleand (I don't know why, because it is provided by polish cable company).

Comment: See Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: You might try the iwlist scan output, and check for quality/signal strength.  5GHz doesn't go through walls/floors as easily as 2.4GHz.

Answer (score 1):

See what freq your Linux wireless card supports:

`iwlist wlan0 freq` # change wlan0 for your wireless network device name

Note the highest 5Ghz frequency supported. Higher channels work better than lower channels. Don't use any of the **radar detection** channels.

Go to your router and change the 5Ghz channel and change it from **Auto** to the highest rate found in the first step. Recheck your Linux connectivity.

Check your tablet for 5Ghz connectivity. Change the router 5Ghz channel if required, but staying within the supported wireless card range of your Linux machine.

**Update #1:**

In your `iwlist wlp8s0 frequency`, the only 5Ghz channels that match up are 36 through 48, so set your router's 5Ghz channel to one of those.

Look at /etc/default/crda. What country code do you see there?

Comment: Setting `REGDOMAIN=PL` in */etc/default/crda* partially help to get rid off vanishing `iw reg get` entry, but overall inability to connect on 5G band keeps the same. I'm trying to connect by entering channels manually from the intersection of `iwlist wlp8s0 frequency`, `iw list` and set of channels provided by my WiFi router = { 36l, 36, 40, 40u, 44l, 44, 48, 48u, 52l, 52, 56, 56u, 60l, 60, 64, 64u, 100l, 100, 104, 104u, 108l, 108, 112, 112u, 116, 132l, 132, 136, 136u, 140 }. It's trying to connect, but falls back asking me for password (I check on phone its correctness).

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek  Are you using WPA2/AES? Do you have wpasupplicant installed?

Comment: Of couse, my wpa_supplicant version is 2.9 and on router side the mode is set to WPA-Personal, Authentication = WPA2, Encryption = AES, Key Interval = 600 seconds. As I wrote before, the 2.4G connection works well and even some time ago I used to use 5G on older Ubuntu versions (prior 20.x).

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek I'm not sure I understand... if you set the routers 5Ghz channel to one of the channels from 36 through 48, aren't you able to connect to it then? Have you rebooted the router, and the computer?

Comment: I rebooted both of them. All changes took effect (I've checked it on phone). By the way, I haven't edited the wpa_supplicant manually and let it to netplan. In file */etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml* there're only 3 lines:`network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager`

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek What happens if you set the router's 5Ghz channel to 48, aren't you able to connect to it? What happens? Your .yaml file looks fine.

Comment: In question body I added the output of `journalctl -f -u NetworkManager` lines where it tries to connect 5G.

Comment: 2.4G has Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm and it connects well. 5G has Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm and fails.

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek It looks like your router, and/or NetworkManager GUI is set to WPA, not WPA2 (only). Check your router setting first.

Comment: @haynnema In Update #2 I've enclosed the screenshot of NetworkManager and router settings. Router is set only to **WPA2** and not **WPA/WPA2**.

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek Do you have an external USB 5Ghz adapter you can try?

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek Does your 5Ghz wireless password contain any special characters?

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek Status please...

Comment: @AdamPrzedniczek Status please...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with EliteBook 2570p [2012] with Zorin Lite. The machine would connect to 2.4 GHz-network but not 5 GHz, although the network was visible.

Solution was: Disable WPA2/WPA3 in Router - Use WPA1/WPA2 in stead for the 5GHz